# How to create dynamic self-sizing height UITableViewCell in swift?

Tags: swift, uitableview, dynamic

Hey I have a tableview controller and I want to create dynamic cell height with label and ImageViews. I tried something like below but it doesn't work for me. Where is the mistake about code. Any idea ?

```
class NotificationsPageController: UITableViewController{

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    tableView.register(NotificationCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: notCell)
    view.backgroundColor = .black
    tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 60
}

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return UITableView.automaticDimension
}

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
      return 60
  }

 class NotificationCell: UITableViewCell {

override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
      super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
   backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 18/255, green: 18/255, blue: 18/255, alpha: 1)

    setNotificationAnchors()

}

fileprivate func setNotificationAnchors() {

    addSubview(notiType)
    notiType.anchor(top: topAnchor, left: leftAnchor, bottom: nil, right: rightAnchor, paddingTop: 4, paddingLeft: 6, paddingBottom: 0, paddingRight: 20, width: 0, height: 0)
    //notiType.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: notiImage.centerYAnchor).isActive = true



    addSubview(notiImage)
    notiImage.anchor(top: nil, left: nil, bottom: nil, right: rightAnchor, paddingTop: 0, paddingLeft: 0, paddingBottom: 0, paddingRight: 4, width: 0, height: 0)
    notiImage.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: centerYAnchor).isActive = true



}

required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}
}
```

Comment: Can you show the output that you're getting. And are the constraints applied properly in the cell?

Comment: In the output long texts passing to above another cell. And I am not using any constraint for cell. Just using constraint for label texts and imageview. Should I use constraint for cell ?

Comment: Yes you need to use constraints. Otherwise how will the cell calculate its size automatically?

Comment: @SwiftTry - search (on google or wherever) for `swift self-sizing table view cell`. You'll find many, many articles, tutorials, examples, etc. Do a little reading and give it a try.

Comment: yes I tried google search but they dont work for me. I asking for may be you can see any missing point like constraints thank you! How can I give constraint for cells can you suggest any source for this

Comment: @SwiftTry - You need to provide much more information. Is your `NotificationCell` code-only? Or is it a prototype designed in Storyboard / Interface Builder? Do you have one label and one image view? Multiples of each? Laid-out horizontally, vertically or a combination?

Comment: I added on edit my tableview cell and I am not using storyboard. I have just one label and one ımageview in cell. some label texts longer than others and ı want to dynamic cell height because of this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I ***strongly*** recommend you learn how constraints and auto-layout work. The fact that the code you posted shows you are using a `.anchor(top:left:bottom:right:...)` type of "constraint helper" indicates that you don't understand it yet.

So, here is a simple example. Note that this is not a *complete* implementation, but it should get you headed in the right direction:

```
class NotificationCell: UITableViewCell {

    let notiType: UILabel = {
        let v = UILabel()
        v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        v.numberOfLines = 0
        return v
    }()

    let notiImage: UIImageView = {
        let v = UIImageView()
        v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return v
    }()

    override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 18/255, green: 18/255, blue: 18/255, alpha: 1)

        setNotificationAnchors()

    }

    fileprivate func setNotificationAnchors() {

        contentView.addSubview(notiType)
        contentView.addSubview(notiImage)

        let g = contentView.layoutMarginsGuide

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([

            // constrain label Top, Leading, Bottom to contentView margins
            notiType.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.topAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            notiType.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            notiType.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.bottomAnchor, constant: 0.0),

            // constrain image view Right and centerY to contentView margins
            notiImage.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            notiImage.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.centerYAnchor, constant: 0.0),

            // guessing square (1:1 ratio) image view, 24 x 24
            notiImage.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 24.0),
            notiImage.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: notiImage.widthAnchor),

            // leave 8-pts space between label and image view
            notiType.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: notiImage.leadingAnchor, constant: -8.0),

        ])

        // during development, so we can easily see the element frames
        notiType.backgroundColor = .cyan
        notiImage.backgroundColor = .red

    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}

class ExampleTableViewController: UITableViewController {

    let notCell = "notCell"

    let theData: [String] = [
        "Single line label.",
        "This lable will have enough text that it will need to wrap onto multiple lines.",
        "Another single line cell.",
        "Here is a description of a table view cell: Defines the attributes and behavior of cells in a table view. You can set a table cell's selected-state appearance, support editing functionality, display accessory views (such as a switch control), and specify background appearance and content indentation.",
        "This is the fifth row.",
    ]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        tableView.register(NotificationCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: notCell)
    }

    // MARK: - Table view data source

    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return theData.count
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: notCell, for: indexPath) as! NotificationCell

        cell.notiType.text = theData[indexPath.row]

        // set image here...
        //cell.notiImage.image = ...

        return cell
    }

}
```

Result - Multi-line label (cyan background) and 24x24 image (red background):

[image]

By the way... Step-by-step tutorials on this can be found in many, many places - a little tough to think you searched and couldn't find anything like this.

Answer (score 0):

Follow the steps below:

Add the below lines in ViewDidLoad

```
tableView.dataSource = self
tableView.delegate = self

// Set automatic dimensions for row height
tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
tableView.estimatedRowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
```

In `XIB` or `Cell` if you have label update the `numberOLines = 0` and make the `lineBreakMode = truncateTail`

Update constraints to `top`, `bottom`, `right` and `left`  to its `superView`